# How to upload long blob (image) to mysql database using java and retrieve in php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, blob

I am working on a project where I need to upload images to the database and retrieve the same from database.

I need the image to be uploaded from an android device using java.
Here is what  i have implemented

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I am inserting the byte array to the database.
And here is my php code to retrieve the same :

```
 /**
*Get profile_pic*/
public function callmethod($userId){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE unique_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$userId); 
    //$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    //$photo = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($profile_pic);
    $stmt->fetch();
     //$obj->picture = base64_encode($profile_pic);
    //echo $obj;

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($profile_pic); ?>" />';
}
```

The problem that I am facing here is that the files are getting uploaded to the database but when I am retrieving the image from the database the variable `$profile_pic` is empty, hence the image is not being displayed.

I need it to be able to retrieve the image using java in android. can I do that by just encoding the value retrieve with `json` format?

Pleas let me know what I am doing wrong.
TIA

Comment: The answer is you are making your life needlessly complicated by storing files in a database. It's simpler and more efficient (both from coding and storage/retrieval perspective) to store the files on the file system.

Comment: Please let me think what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /**
*Get profile_pic*/
public function callmethod($userId){
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE unique_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$userId); 
//$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
//$photo = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($profile_pic);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$profile_pic."' />";
}
 //$obj->picture = base64_encode($profile_pic);
//echo $obj;


}
```

ok try this code this.you don't need 
    `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");` 
function. this are error in your php code. this code will create img tag with basc64.

now for android part.

change this in php.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$profile_pic."' />";
}
```

to

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $profile_pic;
}
```

and this would be your android part.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Comment: I have tried out the above code, it gave me the result for the `profile_pic` variable but when I try it out with the image tag it still shows nothing, I just get an icon with broken image.

Comment: you are already  saving image in base64 format right? i completely missed that. so in php you don't need `base64_encode()` function again, so i am updating my code, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately the decoding in the android development part not showing the image

Comment: there must be error in logcat what it is..can your share?

Comment: I have got it worked out.. I was storing only strings in my SQLite DB instead of blob