# Converting bitmap into Base64 not encoding correctly in android.. I not getting image back when decoding

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

This is my code and I tried lot of code varieties already...

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){ 
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); 
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray(); 
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes,Base64.DEFAULT); 
    return encodedImage; 
}
```

---

Comment: Any body got the answers....??

Comment: Please refer this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224056/android-bitmap-to-base64-string)

Comment: Yea sir I have tried that too... But result is same.. The conversion is taking place but i think it is not well formatted..

Comment: what do you need `Base64.encodeToString` for? why cannot you use raw bytes instead?

Comment: i need to upload this file into mysql..

Comment: I am using php post method to upload.

Comment: and you need Base64 for that? are you aware that Base64 makes your data bigger by 33%? so if your raw data is 1kB, Base64 makes it ~1.3kB

Comment: ok then how can i upload image can suggest any good links or explain how can i do it without base64

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to encode and decode image:

```
//Compress img and save
private String encodeBitmapAndSave(Bitmap bitmap1) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

//Decompress img 
private Bitmap decodeFromFirebaseBase64(String image) throws IOException {
    byte[] decodedByteArray = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedByteArray.length);
}
```

Comment: yup !but you didn't post how you decoding it. And make sure your Bitmap is not empty.

Comment: I have checked bitmap is ok its displaying correctly.. But the encoded string is not getting well formatted

Comment: hello.... The encoding is correct , i can decode that image from same activity and gets image back... But i need to upload this data string into my sql ... but when uploaded if the original image size is less than 100 kb, But it shows around 1mb in mysql.. Can u please help.

Comment: @Sayandh you must be doing something wrong while saving Base64 into mysql. You should use `blobe` type for it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11790199/2404262)

Comment: The data type on database is currect is medium blob... and i am sending the data as string to the php page using nameValuepair...

Comment: @Shruti hei can i get complete code for upload image to mysql from android using php... I think the problem is on php code.. Is it need to decode base64 to upload image as blob on mysql.. Please reply..

Comment: @Sayandh I haven't used php to upload image; will check and tell you in some time.

Comment: @Shruti thanks.. is there any other good option to upload image into mysql database..

Comment: @Sayandh check if  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766751/how-to-upload-long-blob-image-to-mysql-database-using-java-and-retrieve-in-php) link works

Comment: @Shruti no its not worked... I didnt get any working methode to store image in mysql database.. Still searching...